# How is immutability practically implemented in the design of Scala applications?

Tags: scala

Being new to scala and a current java developer, scala was designed to encourage the use of immutability to class design.

How does this translate practically to the design of classes? The only thing that is brought to my mind is case classes.  Are case classes strongly encouraged for defining data? Example? How else is immutability encouraged in Scala design of classes?

As a java developer, classes defining data were mutable. The equivalent Scala classes should be defined as case classes?

Comment: I don't understand why people want to close this question. The question looks clear to me, and not at all subjective.

Comment: thanks Daniel. I hope this question is not closed before others can share their answers as well.

Comment: Here is a possible implementation for a cyclic domain model:


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540385/immutable-domain-model-in-scala-how-to-make-this-implementation-more-abstract

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, case classes certainly help, but the biggest contributor is probably the collection library. The default collections are immutable, and the methods are geared toward manipulating collections by producing new ones instead of mutating. Since the immutable collections are persistent, that doesn't require *copying* the whole collection, which is something one often has to do in Java.

Beyond that, for-comprehensions are monadic comprehensions, which is helpful in doing immutable tasks, there's tail recursion optimization, which is very important in immutable algorithms, and general attention to immutability in many libraries, such as parser combinators and xml.

Finally, note that you have to ask for a `var` to get some mutability. Parameters are immutable, and `val` is just as short as `var`. Contrast this with Java, where parameters are mutable, and you need to *add* a `final` keyword to get immutability. Whereas in Scala it is as easy or easier to stay immutable, in Java it is easier to stay mutable.

**Addendum**

[Persistent data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) are data structures that *share* parts between modified versions of it. This might be a bit difficult to understand, so let's consider Scala's `List`, which is pretty basic and easy to understand.

A Scala `List` is composed of two classes, known as *cons* and `Nil`. The former is actually written `::` in Scala, but I'll refer to it by the traditional name.

`Nil` is the empty list. It doesn't contain anything. Methods that depend on the list not being empty, such as `head` and `tail` throw exceptions, while others work ok.

Naturally, *cons* must then represent a non-empty list. In fact, *cons* has exactly two elements: a value, and a list. These elements are known as *head* and *tail*.

So a list with three elements is composed of three *cons*, since each *cons* will hold only one value, plus a `Nil`. It must have a `Nil` because a *cons* must point to a list. As lists are not circular, then one of the *cons* must point to something other than a *cons*.

One example of such list is this:

```
val list = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
```

Now, the components of a Scala `List` are *immutable*. One cannot change neither the value nor the list of a *cons*. One benefit of immutability is that you *never* need to copy the collection before passing or after receiving it from some other method: you know that list cannot change.

Now, let's consider what would happen if I modified that list. Let's consider two modifications: removing the first element and prepending a new element.

We can remove one element with the method `tail`, whose name is not a coincidence at all. So, we write:

```
val list2 = list.tail
```

And `list2` will point to the same list that `list`'s *tail* is pointing. Nothing at all was created: we simply reused part of `list`. So, let's prepend an element to `list2` then:

```
val list3 = 0 :: list2
```

We created a new *cons* there. This new *cons* has a value (a *head*) equal to 0, and its *tail* points to `list2`. Note that both `list` and `list3` point to the same `list2`. These elements are being *shared* by both `list` and `list3`.

There are many other persistent data structures. The very fact that the data you are manipulating is immutable makes it easy to share components.

One can find more information about this subject on the book by Chris Okasaki, [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504), or on his freely available [thesis](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) by the same name.

Comment: Either I don't understand your last paragraph or it is seriously misleading. You make it sound as if having `var` instead of `val` would grant you mutability while it only allows you to reassign some variable.

Comment: @Raphael, reassigning a variable is mutability.  Any identifier declared as `var` is mutable, and any class with a `var` property is considered mutable.

Comment: Daniel, could you say more about _persistent_ part, please? There is some `copy-on-change` mechanism, or something else?

Comment: @Raphael All mutability can be reduced to a `var` somewhere. If I have a `val` pointing to a mutable object, then that object is mutable because it has a `var`, or refers directly or indirectly to some other object that has one. In fact, we can state the reverse: in the absence of `var` (and rules-breaking reflection), everything is immutable. Of course, one can be immutable and still have side effects, with I/O.

Comment: Daniel, I get your intended meaning and I understand Scala's semantics, but it read as if having `var x` made `x` mutable. Aside from that, explaining it the way you do is misleading, too, as you *can* have immutable classes with `var`. Typical definitions of immutability require only that an object's view never changes, not its state remains the same. This enables you (in general) to have term sharing, lazy evaluation and more when implementing immutable classes (say, datastructures). Demanding all state to be unchangeable is stronger than that.

Comment: But then, Scala's `val` is weaker than unchangeable state as you can have `lazy val`.

Comment: @Raphael Sorry, I don't read that. I stated that having a `var` is a necessary condition for mutability, not that having a `val` is a necessary condition for immutability.

Comment: Yes. I'm not saying you wrote something wrong. It's only that people tend to read equalities where only implications hold, so I thought you might want to clarify/extend your answer. Esp regarding the OP, "Just use `val` everywhere" is correct advice, but not the whole truth. (Also, there might be cases where "having `val` everywhere" does not lead to immutability. I seem to remember something about localized strings in Java.)

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - So you're basically saying that immutability is baked into Scala. And generally there's not much we have to do to implement immutability in our classes? OR Should we also be generally using (1) val over var when defining our variables (2) using cases classes as much as possible (not the whole truth as Raphael mentioned) - Your answer seems to explain how immutability is baked into Scala as opposed to what is generally encouraged to implement immutability in our class design.

Comment: @onejigtwojig No, that's not what I'm saying. I'm answering your question as best as I can. Perhaps it is better if someone else answers it, because I don't know how else to make it clear.